# Yii2 Advanced with nginx docker

Tags: docker, nginx, yii2

I want to start development Yii2 Advanced with nginx using docker.
I have try using repository https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-docker or https://github.com/dmstr/docker-php-yii2
i dont know how to place my application. they just give explanation how to run docker, but not describe how to place my application. can help me how to with success application running?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions on the [main page docs](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#installing-using-docker)? If yes, what failed?

Answer (score 0):

Your root directory should be [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jhzo.png), as described in the docker-compose file. Just create and init yii2 in this dir